# Is Black Ops 3 cross-platform?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

Can I play Call of Duty: Black Ops 3 on my PC vs my friend on an Xbox One?
I have Windows 10 but I don't have an Xbox.
And can I play Steam games with a Xbox controller?

Comment: That second question should be asked separately (if it hasn't been already).

Comment: Hey Filip. Yes, as @DangerZone mentioned, your question should probably be edited to remove the question about steam games and controllers to keep the question focused. There are [several questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=steam%20controller%20support) about determining Steam controller support by game.

Comment: Removing console tags as question is in context of pc and xbox, but is not specific to them. This also applies to other variants of the game.

Answer (score 5):

**No.**
Every platform has their own dedicated game servers.

Answer (score -2):

No is the wrong answer.  Microsoft announced you can now play cross platform, but it's up the the game developers to allow it.

http://www.news.com.au/technology/home-entertainment/gaming/xbox-one-now-supports-crossplatform-multiplayer-with-ps4-and-other-consoles/news-story/e7855860a7f4b095c8275a5dfdb51ed2

Comment: Which is great for other games, but we're not asking across all games on XBox; we're asking specifically for one single game.